# How to authenticate Azure Service Management Requests via AAD

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-management-api

I've tried 3 ways with no result:

1. According to this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx I've registered new web application in AAD with permissions to Access Azure Service Management API (steps 1-9) and written the recommended two lines of code to acquire the token:

```
    var context = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}");
    var result = context.AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientId, new Uri(redirectUri));
```

, but it fails with the exception:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' occurred in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll
Additional information: AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.
Trace ID: aa2d6962-5aea-4f8e-bed4-9e83c7631887
Correlation ID: f7f1a61e-1720-4243-96fa-cff182150931
```

2. Also I've tried:

```
    var context = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}");
    var result = context.AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/", new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret));
```

where clientSecret is secret app key of my application.
This version returns a token, but requests with this token returns *403 Forbidden:The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription*.

3. The last, I've found http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud_solution_architect/archive/2015/03/02/authenticating-azure-service-management-api-with-azure-ad-user-credentials.aspx, which recommends:

```
    var context = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", tenantId));

    // TODO: Replace with your Azure AD user credentials (i.e. admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com)
    string user = "{YOUR-USERID]";
    string pwd = "{YOUR-USER-PASSWORD}";
    var userCred = new UserCredential(user, pwd);

    AuthenticationResult result =
    await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientId, userCred);
```

but it also fails with the same exception as in the first case...

Could you please assist me?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: Changing to native means that you are authenticated on behalf of the user, so you didnt find a solution where its the application thats authenticated to talk with the api?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change the "Application Type" to "NATIVE CLIENT APPLICATION" while creating the application in the Azure portal.

Comment: Thank you @kerem, 1st and 3rd approaches works with "Native Client App"!

Comment: Is this possible after it has been created?