# Azure API failed to authenticate the request

Tags: azure, azure-management-api

I am using the next code to get the token for Azure AD authentication

```
errorMessage = "";
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        var context = new AuthenticationContext(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["login"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"]),false);
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]);
        try
        {
            result = context.AcquireToken(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiEndpoint"], clientCredential);
        }
        catch (AdalException ex)
        {
            if (ex.ErrorCode == "temporarily_unavailable")
            {
                errorMessage = "Temporarily Unavailable";
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                errorMessage = "Unknown Error";
                return null;
            }
        }
        string token = result.AccessToken;
        var credential = new TokenCloudCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["subscriptionId"],token);
        //string certificateString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["managementCertificate"];
        //var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64cer));
        return credential;
```

After that I am doing the next to create a website in Azure

```
            using (var computeClient = new WebSiteManagementClient(credentials))
        {
            var result = computeClient.WebSites.IsHostnameAvailable(websiteName);
            if (result.IsAvailable)
            {
                await computeClient.WebSites.CreateAsync(WebSpaceNames.WestEuropeWebSpace, new WebSiteCreateParameters() {
                    Name= websiteName,
                    ServerFarm= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servicePlanName"]
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return ResultCodes.ObjectNameAlreadyUsed;
            }
        }
```

But every time I execute that I got the following error:

> ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.

I tried to import the management certificate as they said here:
https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/security-and-compliance/windows-azure-management-certificates/

And also tried this one:
http://technetlibrary.com/change-windows-azure-subscription-azure-powershell/198

For importing management certificate.
Also I gave the application permissions to access management API.

Comment: You're not alone. Please keep an eye out for this thread as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305581/how-to-authenticate-azure-service-management-requests-via-aad (see step 2 there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD Authentication DOES NOT use the management certificate authentication.

There is a good documentation and code sample on MSDN on how to resolve your current issue.
[Authenticating Service Management Requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your application does not have permission to access the Azure API's.
Please use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal) to get permissions.
After this please add permissions to access API in app permission or user permission.