# Getting the list of all locations

Tags: rest, azure

I am able to use the computing api. storage api, resource manager api
but when I am trying to get the list of all locations available, I am getting strange authentication exception

to get the list of locations I am sending Get request 
https://management.core.windows.net/xxx/locations

> `ForbiddenError`The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.

is there a need for special authentication?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Are you using Azure Resource Manager API or Service Management API here?

Comment: I am using REST calls - according to the msdn reference

Comment: Which one? Can you share the link and some code?

Comment: the url i am sending is written in the post, i am adding as header the version and the bearer token

Comment: I have seen this error many times in recent days. For example see these threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305581/how-to-authenticate-service-management-requests-via-aad (Step 2) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450610/azure-api-failed-to-authenticate-the-request.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Azure published REST api for the Resource Manager authentication method
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790540.aspx