# How to connect Azure ad on behalf of user with appid?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal, azure-ad-b2c

I need to create schema extension.

Following:
[Create schemaExtension - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/schemaextension_post_schemaextensions)

[image]

Code is :

```
  var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);     
  ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
  AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientCred);
  string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;     
  var responseString = String.Empty;   

  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {

    string requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/schemaExtensions";        
    string postJson = "{\"id\":\"graphlearn_courses\",\"description\": \"Graph Learn training courses extensions\", \"targetTypes\":[\"Group\"], \"properties\": [{ \"name\": \"courseId\",\"type\": \"Integer\"},  {\"name\": \"courseName\",\"type\": \"String\"},  {\"name\": \"courseType\", \"type\": \"String\"}]}";

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    request.Content = new StringContent(postJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    Debug.WriteLine(request.ToString());

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
    responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  }
```

Token :

```
"roles": [
"User.ReadWrite.All",
"Group.Read.All",
"Directory.ReadWrite.All",
"User.Read.All"
],
```

Not getting : `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`

User Credentials :

```
  UserPasswordCredential userCred = new UserPasswordCredential(userId, userPassword);
  var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);
  ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
  AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientId, userCred);      
  string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

Error:

> AADSTS70002: 
>   The request body must contain the following parameter: 
>   'client_secret or client_assertion'

Any ideas on how to connect Azure ad on behalf of user with appid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33305581).

You should change the "Application Type" to "*NATIVE CLIENT APPLICATION*" while creating the application in the Azure portal

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the delegated permission because you are using the client credentials grant to authenticate. You are essentially authenticating as the app, so there is no user involved.

You will need to use a different way to authenticate. Check out [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console) on GitHub.

Especially the AuthenticationHelper class where it does authentication with:

```
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(UserModeConstants.AuthString, false);
AuthenticationResult userAuthnResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GlobalConstants.ResourceUrl,
      UserModeConstants.ClientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.RefreshSession));
TokenForUser = userAuthnResult.AccessToken;
Console.WriteLine("\n Welcome " + userAuthnResult.UserInfo.GivenName + " " +
                              userAuthnResult.UserInfo.FamilyName);
```

Comment: Tried, getting following error The request body must contain the following parameter: 
'client_secret or client_assertion'